# Using Carbon dates in Laravel/Lumen

Tags: laravel-5.1, lumen, php-carbon

I am building a webservice based on the latest version of Lumen to use with a Guzzle 6 client. The webservice is working but when I acces a carbon date on the client with:

```
$newsitem->publish_start->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y')
```

I get the following error:

```
Call to a member function formatLocalized() on a non-object
```

In my webservice 'News' model part I have:

```
protected $dates = [
    'publish_start',
    'publish_end'
];
```

If I remove these and access the date with

```
date('Y/m', strtotime($newsitem->publish_start))
```

it all works fine.

What am I missing here? How do I get Carbon dates through the webservice? Do I have to activate Carbon manually on Lumen?

Comment: What happens if you do Carbon::parse($newsitem->publish_start)->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y') ?

Comment: Is `$newsitem` actually an instance of your `News` model? Also what column type is `publish_start`?

Answer (score 5):

You must include the Carbon namespace at the top of your file.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```